# how to get client ip address using asp.net header files?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get client ip address using asp.net header files?

Comment: Let me google for you - http://bit.ly/12Q6dQs

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET there's a property called [`UserHostAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx) on the [`HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) class that will provide you with this information:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
    Response.Write("Your IP address is " + ip);
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin, this is returning normal ip address. But i required public ip address of the client.

Comment: What do you mean by *normal ip address* and how is it different than the public address? If the client is inside the same network as the server and both are on some private network, you will never get any public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.Servervariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

This will returns the IP address of the remote host making the request

Comment: Hi Dor, this is returning normal ip address. But i want public ip which is using by client.